# Openlayers 3 and map captions i18n

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers, internationalization

All captions are displayed in native language when using Openstreetmap as source and that makes map too hard to read when looking at Asian countries.
Is it possible to use user selected language or English transliteration for all map texts?

Answer (score 1):

Displaying Asian place names with Latin characters is not a matter of OpenLayers, but of the used map tile graphics.

You can try some other tile sources, see the OSM wiki about [Map Internationalization](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_internationalization).

Tell us if you have trouble to include those other map tiles in your framework. And always pay attention of the tile producer's licente and terms of use.

Answer (score 1):

In OpenStreetMap, place names can be edited in several languages. For instance, look at [the capital of China](http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/25248662#map=12/39.9579/116.1978), which is defined in OSM in hundreds of languages (see the name:en, name:fr, name:es, etc. tags)
The name that will be rendered in the default OSM tiles is the name under the tag "name", which must be the local name.

This means that one can produce some map tiles using a specific language, for instance, with rendering place names using the `name:en` tag instead of the `name` tag (at least if these places are translated in the database)

And as @stephan75 said, some people did it. See this [map](https://www.openstreetmap.de/karte.html) in German. There are maps in English at [Mapbox here](http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox/maps.html). See this site https://mc.bbbike.org/mc/ for comparing different map tiles.